# python pandas merge looses precision for timestamp value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge timestamps from one dataset to another based on a key. Using left merge goes well but somehow timestamp column looses precision.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [1, 2, 3,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "C": [1573353312, 1573353312, 1573353312]})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['A'], how='left')

df3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not losing precision because of the merge. Pandas is simply showing the scientific notation with 7 significant digits. To display the number in float format, use the following:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```

This will display the full float value with 2 digits after the decimal point.